# Akamai Cache strategy for multiple gated assets in multiple folders

Tags: caching, akamai

I am trying to come up with a strategy to deal with below scenarios
say we have 10 folder with 500 images in each. out of which, only 20 or less in each folder are gated\should not be cached by Akamai.
How do we tell Akamai not to cache those assets alone excluding the rest of the images?
Having secured folders and put secured assets in them is Plan B.

Answer (score 0):

you could put those assets in a subfolder or distinguish them with a particular suffix and then add a caching rule on your akamai configuration that matches the set and sets the cache to whatever you desire